# Function's pointer cast

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Can I cast a function's pointer?
This code report me an error.. 
Can you help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef float (* MyFuncPtrType) (int, char*);
typedef void* (*p) ();

void* some_func ();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyFuncPtrType func;

    some_func = reinterpret_cast<p>(func);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You want some kind of hash table with functions of different signatures?

Comment: I just removed the C tag, as it doesn't make sense here. You are clearly using C++.

Answer (score 2):

First, `void* some_func ();`, `some_func` is not a function pointer. You can't assign it a new value. It should be declared as function pointer as follows:

```
void* (*some_func) ();
```

or

```
p   some_func;
```

Now just write:

```
some_func = (p)func;
```

Check working code @[codepad](http://codepad.org/HMuyOc0S)

In C++ you do `some_func = reinterpret_cast<p>(func);` for c++ check this working code example @[codepad](http://codepad.org/SrP6kiUs)

Comment: I believe OP wanna return `void *` for `some_func`, and also C style casting is a bad choice after all.

Comment: @texasbruce I don't know C++ So i added C style only. in C++ I think it should be: `ome_func = reinterpret_cast<p>(func);`

Comment: AFAIK, *calling* a function through a pointer cast to a different type is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes (not sure for c++) but in C in this answer this is calling `some_func()` causes undefined behaviour. I just provided casting...